# Flutter: Is it ok to use notifier constructor to pass initial value in riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a `TaskEditor` screen and a `TaskEditorController` which extends `Notifier`. State is a `Task` model. I want to make the default value of `TaskEditorController` as the `Task` I get as navigation params from another screen. To achieve that, this is what I am doing. Though this is working fine, I am little concerned over the practice.

```
class TaskEditorController extends Notifier<Task> {
  TaskEditorController(this._initialTask);
  final Task _initialTask;
 
  @override
  Task build() {
    return _initialTask.copyWith();
  }
}

final taskEditControllerProvider = NotifierProvider.autoDispose<TaskEditorController, Task>(
                                   (() => throw UnimplementedError()));
```

And this how I am overriding it.

```
class TaskEditor extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const TaskEditor(this._task);
  final Task _task;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return ProviderScope(
      overrides: [
        taskEditControllerProvider
            .overrideWith(() => TaskEditorController(_task))
      ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "alright". There's nothing inherently wrong with doing this.

But this approach is a bit discouraged. Relying on overriding providers within the widget tree is considered as "advanced" and "should be avoided if possible".

Chances are there's a different solution to your problem which does not involve such practice.

Comment: I tried my level best to avoid scoping using family, but it was becoming very messy.